# Uploading an image on second page keeps using the fetch url from the first page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework

I have a profile page and an event page.  I want to upload a profile pic on the profile page and an event flyer on the event page.

This is how my profile page looks like:

```
 const openFileDialog = () => {
      (document).getElementById("file-upload").click();
    }

    const setImage=(_event: document) => {
      let f = _event.target.files[0];
      const data = new FormData();
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(f)
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        data.append('file', f)

          try {
              fetch(`https://redacted.com/upload_test/${identity}/`, {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
              "x-access-token": jwtoken
              },
              body: data,
              })
                  .then(response => response.json())
                  .then(data => {
                      setProfile_Pic(data)
                  });
          } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)

          }
      }
    }


    <IonAvatar className={ styles.avatar } onClick={openFileDialog}>
                              <input type="file"
                                id="file-upload"
                                accept="image/*"
                                style={{display: "none"}}
                                onChange={setImage}

                                />
                                <IonImg onclick={() => console.log('Profile page')} src={profile}/>
                            </IonAvatar>
                            
                            <div className={ styles.avatarUpload }>
                                <IonIcon icon={ cameraOutline } />
```

When I made that, it works perfectly.  Then I wanted to have an event flyer image for an event page.

Similarly, here is what my event page looks like

```
    const openFileBox = () => {
      (document).getElementById("file-upload").click();
    }

    const setFlyer=(_event: document) => {
      let f = _event.target.files[0];
      const data = new FormData();
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(f)
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        data.append('file', f)

          try {
              fetch(`https://redacted.com/upload_flyer/${micnum}/`, {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
              "x-access-token": jwtoken
              },
              body: data,
              })
                  .then(response => response.json())
                  .then(data => {
                      setMicFlyer(data)
                  });
          } catch (error) {
        console.error('we could have been', error)

          }
      }
    }




<IonAvatar className={ styles.avatar } onClick={openFileBox}>
                              <input type="file"
                                id="file-upload"
                                accept="image/*"
                                style={{display: "none"}}
                                onChange={setFlyer}

                                />
                                <IonImg onclick={() => console.log('Event profile')} src={profile}/>
                                
                            </IonAvatar>
                            
                            <div className={ styles.avatarUpload }>
                                <IonIcon icon={ cameraOutline } />
```

When I go into the event page and try to upload an image, for some reason I see it using the fetch to the url from the first page:  `fetch('https://redacted.com/upload_test/${identity}/'`

Why does this happen and how do I have it use the code from the event page like I would expect?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, in both pages the id = “file-upload” they should be different